# Swift convert Plist(inside NSString) to NSDictionary

Tags: swift, nsstring, nsdictionary

Hello I have a NSString that contains Plist data. I need to convert it to NSDictionary. I have found ways to do it with a file but I want to do it directly in memory. How can I do this with swift? thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot a alot of gooling and playing with it I came across

```
        var data = stringWithPlistInside.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
        var error : NSError?
        var dic: AnyObject! = NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(data!, options: 0, format: nil, error: &error)
```

Just in case anyone else happens to be stuck in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var plist : NSMutableDictionary
let nsDocumentDirectory = NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory
let nsUserDomainMask = NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask
if let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true) {
    if paths.count > 0 {
        if let dirPath = paths[0] as? String {
            let readPath = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("info.plist")
            plist = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: readPath)!
            println(plist)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you understood the question. I have the data in memory already as a String. I do not want to use contentsOfFile. I need to read the data out of the NSString var.